# Counting Number of Words in a delimited String in Linux

Tags: linux

I am Very new to Linux.

I have a delimited String and I want to find out numbers of words in it.

```
line=100|Surender|Linux

echo $line '|' | wc -w
```

The above code gives me 2 . But the expected count is 3 .

Could somebody help me on this

Comment: What you actually do with your code above is echoing two strings and piping them to wc. string one is "100|Surender|Linux", String two is '|'. wc is correctly calculating, as you can see.

Comment: Yes ferdy, Just Learning basic Linux by doing some handson, Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build it up step by step.

`wc` expects white space between words

You could use `tr` to replace '|' to spaces

eg

```
~/tmp$ line="100|Surender|Linux"
~/tmp$ echo $line |tr "|" " "
100 Surender Linux
```

Great, so now push this through a pipe to `wc`

```
~/tmp$ echo $line |tr "|" " " |wc
      1       3      19
```

Answer (score 1):

`wc` understands "words" as "strings of characters separated by whitespace". In your example, there are two words:

```
1 line=100|Surender|Linux
2 |
```

In order to count the "columns", replace vertical bars with spaces:

```
echo "${line//|/ }" | wc -w
```

This would work in `bash`, and uses the "parameter expansion". If it doesn't work in your shell, you can reach for `tr`:

```
echo "$line" | tr '|' ' ' | wc -w
```

Answer (score 1):

Use awk

```
# -F takes delimiter
# NF means no of fields
echo $line | awk -F'|' '{ print NF }'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via array:

```
$ line="foo|bar|blah"
$ IFS="|"; read -ra items <<< "$line"
$ echo ${#items[@]}
3
```

More convinient to my eyes is the awk way shown by @narendra.

And, not to forget, try the python way:

```
$ python -c "print len('${line}'.split('|'))"
3
```